# memcpy implementation issue

Tags: c, memcpy

I am writing a small implementation of memcpy as follows.

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main( )
{
    int i=5;
    int j=4;
    printf("i=%d\t",i);
    swap(&i,&j,sizeof(int));
    printf("i=%d",i);
    return 0;
}


int swap(void *vp1,void *vp2,int size)
{
    char *a=(char *)vp1;
    char *b=(char *)vp2;

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        *a=*b;
        a++;
        b++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this code is

> i=5 i=33

rather than

> i=5 i=4

Can anybody explain what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Works fine for me: `i=5 i=4`. GCC 4.6.3 on 32-bit Linux.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker cunningly named `swap`.

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows `i = 5` and `i = 4`.

Comment: Compiler was also confused! ;-)

Comment: There's no prototype for `swap` in scope when it's called.

Comment: Some obvious problems with your code: 1. The `memcpy()` workalike is named `swap()`, which is horribly confusing.
2. The signature doesn't match.
3. It fails to use `const` for the source pointer.
4. Needless casting from `void *` to `char *`.
5. Will break if given a negative size.
6. Pointless return value.
7. Calling function without first declaring it isn't a sign of good code hygiene. That said, it looks like it should work.

Comment: Also "swap" code `for(int i=0;i<size;i++) ((char*)vp1)[i] = ((char*)vp2)[i];` is shorter and runs about `1.12` times faster on my machine.

Comment: Also `size` is not int, but size_t. I guess that this could cause problems on a 64-bit, big endian system since the integer might not be truncated correctly.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include "stdio.h"
int swap(void *vp1,void *vp2,int size)

{

     int i;

    char *a=(char *)vp1;
    char *b=(char *)vp2;

    for(i = 0; i<size;i++)
    {
     *a = *b;
     a++;
     b++;
     }
    return 0;
}

int main( )

{

    int i=5;
    int j=4;
    printf("i=%d\t",i);
    swap(&i,&j,sizeof(int));
    printf("i=%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please explain any code solutions you give so that the asker can learn how to solve their problem.

Comment: You basically switched the declarations of `swap` and `main`, it doesn't answer the question at all.